# Postgres generate sql output using data dictionary tables

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3, database-metadata

All I need is to get a SQL query output as :

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD CONSTRAINT
FOREIGN KEY (COLUMN_NAME)
   REFERENCES (PARENT_TABLE_NAME);
```

I'm running the below DYNAMIC query USING DATA DICTIONARY TABLES,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   'ALTER TABLE  ' || cs.TABLE_NAME ||
   'ADD CONSTRAINT' || rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME ||
   'FOREIGN KEY' || c.COLUMN_NAME ||
   'REFERENCES' || cs.TABLE_NAME ||
   ' (' || cs.CONSTRAINT_NAME || ') ' ||
   ' ON UPDATE ' || rc.UPDATE_RULE ||
   ' ON DELETE ' || rc.DELETE_RULE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC,
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CS, 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE cs.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  AND cs.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME 
  AND UPPER(cs.TABLE_SCHEMA) = 'SSP2_PCAT';
```

But here even though I'm able to generate the desired output, the concern is its not giving the `PARENT_TABLE_NAME` here, 
rather its giving the same table_name after the `ALTER TABLE` Keywords.

I hope this is clear as we are using Dynamic SQL here and any help is absolutely appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you'd get an answer if you didn't write your question in upper case letters.

Comment: Ok, its not in Upper Case anymore :)

Comment: You have too few join conditions. For example, in `rc`and `cs` the schema name should also be identical. You also need to join with `information_schema.constraint_column_usage` to get the connection between the constraint and the columns on which it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is missing a couple of join tables and join conditions. Also, don't forget that a foreign key can be defined on more than one column. Finally, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection via object names.

But it would be much simpler if you used `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` rather than the `information_schema':

```
SELECT format('ALTER TABLE %s ADD CONSTRAINT %I %s',
              conrelid::regclass,
              conname,
              pg_get_constraintdef(oid))
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint
WHERE contype = 'f'
  AND upper(connamespace::regnamespace::text) = 'SSP2_PCAT';
```

Comment: Thank you Sirr, You guys are so helpful with immense knowledge!
It absolutely worked for my requirement - Laurenz